# GCC doesn't compile when called by system() in Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, linux, gcc

GCC compiles my C script when it's called on the command line by using 
`gcc main.c -o bfcout`. I wrote a script in Ruby where line 36 says `system("gcc main.c -o bfcout")`. I also tried `bash -c #{Shellwords.escape("gcc -Wall #{filename}.c -o bfcompoutput")}`.

But I get an error: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function '_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main'`

There IS a main() function, and as I said, compiling on the command line works! What is wrong here?

EDIT: 
C file looks like this. It is generated by the script. And yes, it's a reference to Brainf***. Sorry for the many lines(and the bad formatting).

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char _c[30000]={};
int ptr=0;
int main(){
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
while (_c[ptr]) {
    ++ptr;
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++ptr;
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++ptr;
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++_c[ptr];
    ++ptr;
    ++_c[ptr];
    --ptr;
    --ptr;
    --ptr;
    --ptr;
    --_c[ptr];
}
++ptr;
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++ptr;
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++ptr;
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
--ptr;
--ptr;
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++ptr;
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
--_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++ptr;
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++ptr;
putchar(_c[ptr]);
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
++_c[ptr];
putchar(_c[ptr]);
return 0;
}
```

Script in Ruby:

```
require 'shellwords'

code = ""

loop do
    x = gets.chomp
    break if x=="__END__"
    code << x
end

code_arr = []

code.split("").each {|ch|
    case ch
    when ">";code_arr << "++ptr;"
    when "<";code_arr << "--ptr;"
    when "+";code_arr << "++_c[ptr];"
    when "-";code_arr << "--_c[ptr];"
    when ".";code_arr << "putchar(_c[ptr]);"
    when ",";code_arr << "_c[ptr] = getchar();"
    when "[";code_arr << "while (_c[ptr]) {"
    when "]";code_arr << "}"
    end
}

filename = "main"

sp = ""

ostr = "#include <stdio.h>\nunsigned char _c[30000]={};#{sp}int ptr=0;#{sp}int main(){#{code_arr.join(sp)+sp}return 0;#{sp}}"
File.open("#{filename}.c","w").write(ostr)
puts ostr
result = system("gcc -Wall #{filename}.c -o ./#{filename}")
puts "Process exited with code #{result}"
```

Comment: Would you mind to post your .c file, please?

Comment: Really strange! Il try to reproduce the error here before telling you something.

Comment: I repeated exactlly the same here and it compiled correctly. I mus assume there is something wrong with your installation. Do you have all the build tools installed?

Comment: It does work in the interactive bash/sh. So everything seems to be installed.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Do you want to see the script in Ruby, too?

Comment: Sure! Maybe there is some hint there about why it is not working.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Alright, it's there.

Comment: Once more it worked fine here! With your code, not my simulation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to a file stream is buffered, you need to flush the buffer before compiling the C file. Change this

```
File.open("#{filename}.c","w").write(ostr)
```

to this

```
File.open("#{filename}.c","w") { |f| f.write(ostr) }
```

The block form automatically closes the file stream, flushing the write.

**Edit:**

A nicer way to do this is to write the code directly to gcc without saving it to an intermediate file.

```
IO.popen("gcc -Wall -o ./#{filename} -xc -", 'w') { |io| io.write(ostr) }
```

If you want more control over the subprocess check out [open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: OK! Just one more question: Would `File.open("#{filename}.c","w").write(ostr).close` also be valid?

Comment: No, write returns the number of bytes read so you'll get a `NoMethodError`. Also see my edit.